Can you access the list of network devices from the command line?
In Finder there is a "Network" item in every window that allows you to view all devices on the LAN. Can you access the same list of devices from the command line?

Sure, the tool is dns-sd
It conducts service delivery using the multicast DNS (mDNS or Bonjour) protocol.
To list all services, I start here.
You’ll want to then change the query for AFP (_afp) or SMB (_smb) since that’s what finder should be showing for file share network discovery. It doesn’t list all devices, just ones advertising a file sharing service.
dns-sd -B _smb._tcp 

